# Outlook web add-in: Execute Function opens new Browser Window

Tags: javascript, manifest, outlook-web-addins

In my Web Add-In I open a new Browser Window with Execute Function:

```
var myWindow = window.open("...");
myWindow.focus();
```

As a result the Browser Window is not in the foreground (like expected) and the browser symbol in the task bar blinks.

Code snippets to bring the window to the foreground are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript open a new browser window (not tab) with address bar disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929239/javascript-open-a-new-browser-window-not-tab-with-address-bar-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not support window.open directly inside of Add-ins. Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026932) for more information.